# DVWA 1.8 - SQL Injection - Change a users password

Tags: mysql, sql-injection

i am experimenting with DVWA in regards of SQLi. (LOW)
I have come so far that i can now see the usernames and passwords located in the table "users" in the database "dvwa".
I was now wondering why I am unable to modify / change / update the password for a specific user by using:

`; update users set password='098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6' WHERE 'user_id'='1' #`

All it does is throwing a syntax error.
Is there any way to achieve this?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i found the solution.

The basic answer is that:

mysql_query() sends a unique query and **single** query to the MySQL server. Therefore everything after the **;** will be ignored as if it was commented out.